# Verification that data inserted into SQL Server table is exactly same from csv source file

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, csv, import, verification

I have a source csv file and I am able to insert this into SQL Server 2005 Express.

I need to write a piece of code that will then verify the production data (inserted from the csv) is exactly the same, row by row and column for column in each row.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What lanaguage do you want it in?

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2005, `EXCEPT` returns any distinct values from the left query that are not also found on the right query. So, if I understood correctly what you want, you can do:

```
select * from table1 except select * from table2

select * from table2 except select * from table1
```

If you don't get any results, both tables are exactly the same.